# background image issue in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a  website using bootstrap3. I used an image as a background to a div but the image is not being displayed in correct ratio. The image being visible is displaying only a portion of it.
My code and css is as under:

```
 <div class="jumbotron"> 

        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12"> 

                <div class="col-md-4">            
                     <div  id="show_div" class="dropdown">Menu
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                          <div id="hello" style="visibility:hidden;" >
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:block!important;" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                 <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Our Services</a></li>
                                 <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                                 <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>                          
                             </ul>
                          </div>                 
                     </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                     <p class="text-center"><a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                     <p class="text-right"><a role="button" href="#" >Sign Up</a></p>
              </div>            
            </div>


        <div class="col-md-12 clear-fix"> </div>
            <div class="cover-container">
                    <div class="inner cover">
                        <h2 class="cover-heading">hello</h1>                        
                        <p class="lead">
                          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#">Login</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
             </div>

       <div class="col-md-12 clear-fix"> </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 botomopdv"> 
            <div class="col-md-4 "> 
            <div class="text-center textwrap">+91-9898976766</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 "> 
            <div class="text-center textwrap"><img src="images/visa.png"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 "> 
                <div class="text-center textwrap">
                <i class="fa fa-youtube fsz fa-inverse"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fsz fa-inverse"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fsz fa-inverse"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fsz fa-inverse"></i> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         </div>             
    </div>
```

My css is like this:

```
.jumbotron{
background-image:url('../images/slide.png');
padding-bottom:1px!important;

}
```

Comment: your code works fine for me, after I swapped the image for one of my own, so maybe its an issue with the image?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem correctly, try adding `background-size:cover`:

```
.jumbotron{
  background-image:url('../images/slide.png');
  padding-bottom:1px!important;
  background-size:cover;         /**** add this line ****/
}
```

Comment: it shouldn't be lost, the image should grow or 'scale to fill' the area. works here http://jsfiddle.net/P9Xrd/1/

Answer (score 1):

all your code is correct but you can experiment with `background-size: 100% 100%;` or `background-size: cover;`